# rcharts weird numbers in the y axis

Tags: r, rcharts

The file to generate the graph can be downloaded from https://db.tt/hHYq0mSA. I'm sharing a link because dput generates a huge output. This is what I'm runing

```
require(rCharts)
dense<-readRDS("dense.RDS")
nPlot(x = "minutes", y = "FBS", data = dense, type = "lineChart")
```

This is what I get

[image: Rcharts]

What are the numbers (63382626 and 67270968) in the Y axis? how can I make them go away?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strange digits are the final digits of the min and max of y

```
> options(digits=12)
> min(dense[,2])
[1] 0.000239026338263
> max(dense[,2])
[1] 0.0417486727097
```

You need to add some formatting rules on the y axis ticks:

```
require(rCharts)
dense<-readRDS("dense.RDS")
n1 <- nPlot(x = "minutes", y = "FBS", data = dense, type = "lineChart")
n1$yAxis(tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return d3.format(',.2f')(d)} !#")
n1
```

[image]

Aternative you can set the domain of the yaxis and keep the digits

```
require(rCharts)
dense<-readRDS("../Downloads/dense.RDS")
n1 <- nPlot(x = "minutes", y = "FBS", data = dense, type = "lineChart")
n1$chart(forceY = c(0, 0.05))
n1
```

[image]

Comment: You can also set `n1$yAxis(showMaxMin = FALSE)` to suppress the min/max numbers on the y-axis.