# rCharts Zeros instead of numbers in the y Axis

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, rendering, rcharts

I get 0 values on the y Axis while plotting a discreteBarChart inside renderChart(), **However**, the highest value of yAxis appears (not 0) but also with some wierd format and commmas (see 2nd screenshot down named **Chart Plot**)

I want to plot 2 columns in **rCharts**, the x Axis is a *character* (countryname) and the yAxis is *numeric* (Collective_Turnover)
I created this variable **(Collective_Turnover)** from the data, it is the **sum of the Net_Turnover**
I tried to put *as.numeric()* before it, but still, getting **0** on the yAxis

```r
data$countryname= as.character(data$countryname)

  output$top10countries <-renderChart({
    topcountries <- 
      arrange(data%>%  
                group_by(as.character(countryname)) %>% 
                summarise(
                  Collective_Turnover= sum(as.numeric(`Net turnover`))
                ), desc(Collective_Turnover))
    colnames(topcountries )[colnames(topcountries )=="as.character(countryname)"] <- "Country"

    topcountries <- subset(topcountries [1:10,], select = c(Country, Collective_Turnover))

    p <- nPlot(Collective_Turnover~Country, data = topcountries , type = "discreteBarChart", dom = "top10countries")
    p$params$width <- 1000
    p$params$height <- 200
    p$xAxis(staggerLabels = TRUE)
    # p$yAxis(axisLabel = "CollectiveTO", width = 50)
    return(p)
  })
```

The output of topcountries in R is a table like this:

[image: topcountriesscreenshot]

that is arranged in descending order... 
and the plot that i get is this:
[image: Chart Plot]

Comment: Thanks @John for editing and for improving my question. Much obliged!

Comment: @John  guys thank you for the improvements suggestions, but since then, I had no reply to my post.. and I got something like I have an option to "reject" your suggestion, which i don't want to reject!! 
totally the opposite! I want to approve the change, but I got another alert that it has been approved already, HOWEVER, I haven't got any reply from any one still.. and this is important to me. 
Can I re-ask the question again? or share it or something.. ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be more help.  I haven't any idea what is causing your problem.  I think that they generally frown upon re-asking questions.  I believe there's an option to add a bounty to a question but I'm not really sure how that works.  I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494614/rcharts-weird-numbers-in-the-y-axis?rq=1  in case that's of any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ticks labels are truncated because they are too long. You need to set the left margin and a padding. To get rid of the commas, use a number formatter.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Country = c("Russian", "Italy", "Spain"), 
  x = c(12748613.6, 5432101.2, 205789.7)
)

p <- nPlot(x ~ Country, data = dat, type = "discreteBarChart")
p$yAxis(tickPadding = 15, tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return d3.format('.1')(d)} !#")
p$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
p
```

[image]